# Retrieve specific data using JSON decode Laravel

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, database, laravel

I'm new to Laravel. I need to retrieve specific data from the database using the JSON decode. I am currently using `$casts` to my model to handle the JSON encode and decode.

This is my insert query with json encode:

```
$request->validate([
        'subject' => 'required|max:255',
        'concern' => 'required'
    ]);

    $issue = new Issue;
    $issue->subject = $request->subject;
    $issue->url = $request->url;
    $issue->details = $request->concern;
    $issue->created_by = $request->userid;
    $issue->user_data = $request->user_data; //field that use json encode
    $issue->status = 2; // 1 means draft
    $issue->email = $request->email;
    $issue->data = '';
    $issue->save();
```

The user_data contains  `{"id":37,"first_name":"Brian","middle_name":"","last_name":"Belen","email":"arcega52@gmail.com","username":"BLB-Student1","avatar":"avatars\/20170623133042-49.png"}`

This is my output:

```
{{$issue->user_data}}
```

What I need to retrieve is only the `first_name`, `middle_name`, and `last_name`. How am I supposed to achieve that? Thank you in ADVANCE!!!!!

Comment: when you are receiving all the user data?

Comment: if you have used model you can get specific details like Table::select('first_name','middle_name ')->where('id', 1)->get();

Answer (score 1):

As per the above code shown by you it will only insert data into the database.For retrieving data you can make use of Query Builder as i have written below and also you can check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects)

$users = DB::table('name of table')->select('first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name')->get();

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend using Resources. It really very helpful laravel feature. Check it out. It is a reusable class. You call anywhere and anytime.

```
php artisan make:resource UserResource
```

Go to your the newly created class `App/Http/Resources/UserResource.php` and drfine the column you want to have in your response.

```
public function toArray($request) {
return [
  "first_name" => $this->first_name,
  "middle_name" => $this->middle_name,
  "last_name" => $this->last_name
 ]
}
```

Now is your controller you can use the UserResource like folow:

```
public function index()
{
    return UserResource::collection(User::all());
}
```

Or after inserting data you can return the newly added data(f_name, l_name...)

```
   $user = new User;
   $user->first_name= $request->first_name;
   $user->middle_name= $request->middle_name;
   $user->last_name= $request->last_name;
   $user->save();

   $user_data= new UserResource($user);
   return $user_data;
```